Problem setting up cgi component of nagios
I'm on Alma Linux 9 and I'm trying to set up Nagios Core 4.4.1 from RPM via epel repo.
I haven't messed with nagios installations for a long time and I recall before you needed to run a FastCGI-wrapper.pl perl script which listened on port 8999 to process cgi requests.
I'm now trying this with the fcgiwrap package. I don't understand how this is supposed to work exactly. I've tried starting the service like this, giving it a label of 'nagios'
systemctl start fcgiwrap@nagios.service
This didn't return anything, but then
systemctl status fcgiwrap@nagios.service
Gives
Jul 06 16:42:11 systemd[1]: Started Simple CGI Server.
Jul 06 16:42:11  fcgiwrap[44053]: Cannot get script name, are DOCUMENT_ROOT and SCRIPT_NAME (or SCRIPT_FILENAME) set and is the script executable?
Jul 06 16:42:11  systemd[1]: fcgiwrap@nagios.service: Deactivated successfully.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Am I supposed to declare these variables in /etc/sysconfig/fcgiwrap  ?
I've seen articles that say this comes from the nginx.conf bu surely the service is supposed to start up correctly and open a socket?
